ASP.NET Core switch to code first approach from database first approach
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API, based on .NET 6.0. Currently, it uses the database-first approach, as a design pattern.
Now, I have a requirement to switch to a code-first approach for running migrations in the code, with EF Core.
Is there a way to switch to code first approach from database-first and preserve the already setup database?
Current solution found, is that to initialize migrations, that would generate a new schema, then transfer the data from previous database separately.
But I am looking for a possible solution to use the previous database and schema in the code first approach, or is the solution mentioned above the correct way to approach my requirement.

There is tooling support for these migrations: try and see Code First Migrations with an existing database and, in particular, Reverse Engineer Model in Microsoft's documentation.
